# Python application works when installed via pip but not when running directly

Tags: python, python-click

I need help setting up my directory structure for a python application. It is a command line application (using Click, if that matters).

My directory structure looks like this:

```
mycli
├── mycli
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mycli.py
└── setup.py
```

In `mycli/mycli/__init__.py` I have one line of code:

```
__application__ = "my-cli"
```

In `mycli/mycli/cli.py` I have this:

```
from mycli import __application__
import click
import sys

@click.group()
def my_cli():
    """ rest of my code """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(my_cli())
```

Finally, in my `setup.py`, I have added an entry point so that I can use this application on the command line:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'my-cli=mycli.cli:my_cli',
    ],
},
```

I can install my application using `pip install -e .` and then execute `my-cli` as expected. This works.

The problem I am having is that I want to run `python mycli/cli.py` as well. This is useful for debugging purposes. It fails to read the `__application__` though:

```
$ python mycli/cli.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycli/cli.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mycli import __application__
ImportError: cannot import name '__application__'
```

What do I need to do with my project layout so that I can continue to use the `entry_points` in `setup.py` AND be able to run my application with `python mycli/cli.py`?

I tried to change the import to

```
from .mycli import __application__
```

But I receive these errors:

When running `python mycli/cli.py`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.mycli'; __main__ is not a package
```

The entry_point breaks with:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '__application__'
```

Comment: Try `from .mycli import __application__`

Comment: @Sparky05 That fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named __main__.mycli'; __main__ is not a package` when I run `python mycli/cli.py` and also breaks the entry_point with `ImportError: cannot import name '__application__'`

Comment: Have you tried moving the `mycli.py` one folder up or import directly from the file `__application__`(e.g. `from .cli import __application__`) is inside?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a conflicting namespace.  Your program has the same name as your module.  So:

```
from mycli import __application__
```

tries to import from `mycli.py`, not from `mycli/__init__.py`.  I suggest you rename your script to `my-cli.py`.